# Inserting hebrew values in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hebrew

I've been trying to update a record with hebrew texy into a DB table, and it shown as "??????".
Here's my command:

```
UPDATE HebrewTbl
   SET HebrewVal = N'ראשונה'
 WHERE Id = 1
GO
```

All solutions I found over the Internet ended up in adding that N  in the beginning, but in my case the problem continues.

Please advise.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your column set to nvarchar?  Do you have the correct collation enabled to allow Hebrew characters?

Comment: Until we see your table definition and your collation settings, we can't help. Please post those.

Comment: @TTeeple column is set to varchar, does it matter?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms184391.aspx COLLATE i think it will help you

Comment: yes it matters. NVARCHAR is the datatype to store unicode characters.

Comment: Yes, varchar is restriced to 8-bit code pages.  Nvarchar is used for unicode characters (those characters outside of the standard set)

Comment: To add to 1010 and TTeeple, This might help [NVARCHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

Comment: if you use varchar you have to use the correct collation as suggested in previous comments. please post the definition of your table (with collation)

Comment: IT WAS THE COLUMN DEFINITION AS @TTeeple MENTIONED!! THANKS YOU!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Actually, if the collation is set to a hebrew collation then you can use varchar as well.

Comment: @ZoharPeled if collation is forced on an operation and varchar is used, will the storage still be half that of nvarchar? Otherwise I can see no benefit forcing collation.

Comment: @JohnBell That's an interesting question that I don't know the answer to. I was just pointing out the fact that it's possible to save hebrew into varchar columns if they have the collation to support it.

Comment: @JohnBell and Zohar: Forcing collation on an operation implies it is being set in the query to override the column's actual collation setting. But regardless, collation does not imply storage, only sorting and comparisons. `VARCHAR` is (almost) always single-byte and `NVARCHAR` is (almost) always double-byte. Also, `NVARCHAR` for most collations is UCS-2, not exactly the same as Unicode. Only the newer "Supplementary Character" collations (ending in `_SC`) are actual Unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copied from comment so question can be set to answered per suggestion of [this post](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931#1931).

Set your column to nvarchar and have the correct collation enabled to allow Hebrew characters.

Comment: This is stackoverflow, not [Jeopardy.](http://www.jeopardy.com/) please phrase your answer as an answer and not in the form of a question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled and TTeeple: just FYI, collation is not _required_ to store Hebrew characters. In the UCS-2 and Unicode schemes, those code-points are well outside of the 128 - 255 range that is controlled by Code Pages (which are tied to various collations that affect VARCHAR, not NVARCHAR data). Setting a Hebrew collation will, however, ensure proper sorting and comparisons.