# Stored procedure Inserts Hebrew characters into an NVARCHAR column, but SELECT shows "?"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode, collation

When I `SELECT` from the table, the data that I stored is stored as question marks.

`@word` is a parameter in my stored procedure, and the value comes from the C# code:

```cs
string word = this.Request.Form["word"].ToString();

cmd.Parameters.Add("@word", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = word;
```

My stored procedure is like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ....
(
   @word nvarchar(500)
   ...
)

Insert into rub_translate (language_id,name)
values (8 ,@word COLLATE HEBREW_CI_AS )
```

My database, and the column, is using the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation and I cannot change them.

Can anybody give me a solution how can I solve this problem just by modifying the column or the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting hebrew values in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326013/inserting-hebrew-values-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Can you show us the code where you assign the value to `@word`? You'll have problems if you set it to a string literal but forget the N prefix, for example.

Comment: @Bridge `@word` is a parameter in my stored procedure and the value comes from the C# code : 
 `string word = this.Request.Form["word"].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@word", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = word;`

Comment: OK - and in the stored procedure definition, is the parameter also of type NVARCHAR?

Comment: @Bridge Yes, sure

Comment: And what's the collation of the column itself? `SELECT COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'rub_translate' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'name';`

Comment: Please see the update I just made to my answer regarding checking the actual value within the app code, as received by the calling web page.

Comment: @Bridge `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is the collation of column and i cannot change it.

Comment: @srutzky The value comes ok like hebrew letters, and in my stored procedure with update it works but it doesnt work with insert

Comment: Anyway i think i just found the way how can handle this, thank you all

Comment: @Anonymuslegacy It works with `UPDATE` but not `INSERT`? That doesn't make any sense. Is there a Trigger on the table? Is it the same stored procedure? There is a difference somewhere. At the very least, please post what the actual problem and solution were. Thanks.

Comment: @srutzky After insert i made an update of the row inserted and now works, i know is silly thing, Thanks

Comment: @Anonymuslegacy Thanks for that info. Are you concatenating the variable to a literal in the insert? Are you sure that there is no trigger there? There is clearly something going on here that is definitely _not_ normal. There is no difference between INSERT and UPDATE for what you are doing. It is not an issue of "silly", it is an issue of you working around a mechanism that you are trying to ignore but could be doing something else that you don't see or might show up at some other point causing unexpected behavior. It is in your best interest to look for the actual cause here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to do the following:

1. Declare the input parameter in the app code as `NVARCHAR` (you have done this)
2. Declare the input parameter in the stored procedure as `NVARCHAR` (no code is shown for this)
3. Insert or Update a column in a table that is defined as `NVARCHAR` (you claim that this is the case)

When using `NVARCHAR` it does not matter what the default Collation of the Database is. And actually, when using `NVARCHAR`, it won't matter what the Collation of the column in the table is, at least not for properly inserting the characters.

Also, specifying the `COLLATE` keyword in the `INSERT` statement is unnecessary and wouldn't help anyway. If you have the stored procedure input parameter defined as `VARCHAR`, then the characters are already converted to `?` upon coming into the stored procedure. And if the column is actually defined as `VARCHAR` (you haven't provided the table's DDL) then if the Collation isn't `Hebrew_*` then there is nothing you can do (besides change either the datatype to `NVARCHAR` or the Collation to a `Hebrew_` one).

If those three items listed at the top are definitely in place, then the last thing to check is the input value itself. Since this is a web app, it is possible that the encoding of the page itself is not set correctly. You need to set a break point just at the `cmd.Parameters.Add("@word", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = word;` line and confirm that the value held in the `word` variable contains Hebrew characters instead of `?`s.

**ALSO:** you should never create a string parameter without specifying the max length/size. The default is 30 (in this case, sometimes it's 1), yet the parameter  in the stored procedure is defined as `NVARCHAR(500)`. This could result in silent truncation ("silent" meaning that it will not cause an error, it will just truncate the value). Instead, you should always specify the size. For example:

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add("@word", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500).Value = word;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just insert it as-is, since it's unicode and then [select it with a proper collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx):

```
    declare @test table([name] nvarchar(500) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS);

    declare @word nvarchar(500) = N'זה טקסט.';

    insert into @test ( [name] ) values  ( @word );

    select [t].[name] collate Hebrew_CI_AS from @test as [t]
```

Or you can [change the collation of that one column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx) in the table all together. But remember that there is a drawback of having a different collation from your database in one or more columns: you will need to add the collate statement to queries when you need to compare data between different collations.